# Magento 1.9 pagination not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, pagination

I am working on **Magento 1.9** and facing some **Issue with the pagination on search page.**
I have **Selected "16" in products per page** but it is **Showing random number of products on pages.**
same issue with list and grid view in all possible value options.
I have already tried re-indexing, cache flush.

Guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try reindexing from admin and test.

Comment: @ChiragRajput already done.

Comment: Can you check for override of any extention with search page file. You can use admin path hint for make sure its using core files. Not any extention files.

Comment: checked and found not any extension is overriding these files.

Answer (score 0):

First you confirm your Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values in Configuration > catalog admin setting are correct like below screenshot and then clear cache and then re-index else if still issue not resolved then check your pagination code in toolbar.phtml.

[image]